# forewrd emails with google apps script as txt file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing to seek your help with an issue I am having. I am trying to forward emails with the label "processed" to a specific email address as txt files, but the script I am using is not working.

```
// Create a new label called "Processed" if it doesn't already exist.
function createLabel() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Processed');
  if (!label) {
    GmailApp.createLabel('Processed');
  }
}

// Create a text file for each message and send it as an attachment to a specified email address.
function createTxtFilesAndSendEmail() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Processed');
  if (!label) {
    GmailApp.createLabel('Processed');
    label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Processed');
  }
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox label:to_process');
  var recipient = 'abhotline@gmail.com';
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      if (!message.isInTrash() && !message.isStarred() && !message.isUnread() && !message.isDraft() && !message.isImportant() && !message.getLabels().includes(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SENT'))) {
        var fileName = message.getSubject() + '.txt';
        var content = message.getPlainBody();
        var attachment = Utilities.newBlob(content, 'text/plain', fileName);
        var emailSubject = 'Forwarded message: ' + message.getSubject();
        var emailBody = 'Please see attached file for message content.';
        try {
          MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, emailSubject, emailBody, {attachments: [attachment]});
          threads[i].addLabel(label);
        } catch (error) {
          Logger.log('Error sending email: ' + error);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


// Remove the "to_process" label from messages that have been processed.
function removeLabel() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('to_process');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}

// Main function that calls the other functions.
function processEmails() {
  createLabel();
  createTxtFiles();
  removeLabel();
}
```

Thank you for your time and assistance.

the function `createLabel` and `removeLabel` are working but `createTxtFiles` is not working

Comment: Where is the code failing.  Please do some trouble shooting of your own.

Comment: "but `createTxtFiles` is not working" Could this be because there is no function of that name BUT there is a `createTxtFilesAndSendEmail()`

Comment: you are rights but now is  `removeLabel` not working and its showing the expected results